# In Elder Sign, what is the distinction between completing and defeating a task?

Tags: elder-sign

The [faq](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05-faq-web.pdf) says that Mandy Thompson's ability should read

> Once per day, after any player has rolled, Mandy may re- roll 2 dice before determining if the active player was able to defeat a task.

The actual card says "complete" instead of "defeat", so what is the reason for the errata claiming it should say "defeat"?

Comment: Error in the errata? I would interpret that as the same thing, but that's not a solid answer.

Comment: I have the expansion that actually gave me a replacement character sheet for Mandy. I believe it was just to ensure that the wording was consistent. I will double check later if there were any other differences on the cards

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between completing a task and defeating a task.

The difference in wording is - as suspected - for consistency. Additionally, because some tasks are in fact monsters, defeating is a better fit for being the general term than completing.